# Collapsing Side Menu

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I would like to include a left side menu in my master page, but allow this to collapse away to the left to provide more work space in the main 'window.'

How best can I achieve this using plain ASP.NET, or with Telerik as well?  I'd prefer to stick with these, as jQuery and company get complicated once telerik is already at the party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely something you can do with some client side scripting.  I would recommend utilizing the jQuery javascript framework even though you've voiced a concern on this.  I know that Telerik does support jQuery, so depending on your specific needs and uses, this should really not be that big of a deal.

Here are a few links that provide samples on how this can be done...
* [Adiplaz.AwardSpace.com](http://adipalaz.awardspace.com/experiments/jquery/expand_collapse_different_directions.html#expand/collapse)
* [ILoveColors.com](http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/collapsible/#)

Answer (score 0):

You could use **jQuery** or **AJAX Toolkit**.

Comment: I don't think that deserved a down vote.  Yes, I did say I didn't want jQuery, but the AJAX toolkit is, at least, a step in the right direction.